# CakeTime relative time instead of absolute time

Tags: cakephp-2.0

How I can get relative time instead of absolute time by using CakeTime:timeAgoInWords ?

for example:

```
about one week ago
```

instead of

```
1 week, 2 days ago
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create you own method to handle that based on what you want. And you can implement a function `int_to_words()` like [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strval.php#62839)

Something like:

```
function relativeTime($time){
    $arrray = explode(" ",$time); // transform time in array of words
        if(array[1] == "week,"){
           if(array[2]) > 5){
               return "Almost two weeks ago";
           }
           return "About one week ago";
        }else if(array[1] == "weeks"){
           $aux = array[0];
           $number = int_to_words($aux);
           return "About $number week ago";
        }          
        // Read more about the possible CakeTime:timeAgoInWords results
        // and continue to implement the other possibilities here...
}
```